# How to add a watermark to CSV

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add a watermark to a Comma Separated Values file?

I have tried to add an image and word art to a Comma Separated Values file but it doesn't work.

Comment: save it as an excel file and you can set the watermark for the excel file. It basically depends on the tool you use to view the CSV file

Comment: @MuhammadNouman: If you *save it as an Excel file*, it's no longer a CSV, and the question asks about embedding a watermark in a CSV file. You'd only be able to see that watermark when opening the file in Excel (or an Excel-compatible viewer).

Comment: Classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Explain what you think “to add a watermark to CSV” means. Explain how you “tried to add an image”. Explain why you want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

No. CSV is plain text, and does not support binary content. It has no concept of watermarks, images, Word art, or anything else. If you can't add it in Notepad, you can't put it in a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

CSVs are straight text files with no graphical association or connection whatsoever. It is impossible to add a watermark to a CSV.